# Is it legal to change the curriculum of an university degree?

Tags: education, spain

Is it legal to change the curriculum of an university degree?

I mean, suppose you are studying mathematics at the university, and, to obtain your degree, you have to pass 240 ECTS, suppose as well that one day you find that your curriculum has suddendly changed so you have to pass 6 additional ECTS to obtain your degree.

Is this situation legal? I thought curriculumns were immovable so that any change will only affect those who begin their studies one the changes are approved.

Comment: I couldn't find anything on this topic other than this article re: UK Consumer Protection law: https://www.theguardian.com/education/2014/apr/22/are-universities-breaking-consumer-protection-laws

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is legal. Curriculum requirements are policy decisions of an institution, not binding contracts with students. It might be ill advised policy, but it is not prohibited.

Answer (score 2):

Might depend on which University. I fail to read which exact University you are thinking of.

Public Universities in Spain, both transferred (most of them) and non transferred (UNED and... can't remember which one's the other one), have to publish their curricula changes in the [*Boletín Oficial del Estado*](https://boe.es), so two things come with this:

- It's not completely free to change curricula.
- If not a fully and undeniably legal change, at least you are probably going to have a bad time fighting against them in courts, because they have most probably followed a ton of legal provisions and checks.

Comment: An example from section I of BOE: http://boe.es/buscar/doc.php?id=BOE-A-2019-12368

Comment: Another example, from section II of BOE: https://boe.es/buscar/doc.php?id=BOE-A-2019-12086